# ASP.NET MVC Razor <text> tag not accepting less than or equal to operators

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, comparison-operators

I have a JavaScript `if` condition containing some comparison operators (`<=`, `>=`) inside a partial view. This JavaScript is surrounded by MVC the Razor `<text>` tags.

With this, my JS is dynamically loading based on the Model properties. However if I have comparison operators in the JavaScript method, it is throwing an error.

Working scenario:

```
    @if (Model.SomeTrueCondition)
    {
        <text>
        function JSMethod() {
            AnotherJSMethod();
            return;
        }
        </text>
    }
```

Not working scenario (if I call the `AnotherJSMethod()` using comparison operators)

```
    @if (Model.SomeTrueCondition)
    {
        <text>
        function JSMethod() {
            // This if condition containing comparison operators are not being accepted!
            if ($('#aTextBox').val().length <= 0 || $('#bTextBox').val().length <= 0) {
                AnotherJSMethod();
                return;
            }
        }
        </text>
    }
```

I tried moving this JS method in another .js file and tried embedding the below way but I still see the same issues.

```
@section JavaScriptIncludes
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")" />
}
```

Getting below error,

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: End of file or an unexpected character was reached before the "" tag could be parsed.  Elements inside markup blocks must be complete. They must either be self-closing ("<br />") or have matching end tags ("<p>Hello&lt/p>").  If you intended to display a "<" character, use the "<" HTML entity.

[image]

Pl. can someone tell me what am I missing here!

Feel free to correct the question/content/tags in order to reach out to right people.

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code(Not working scenario ) and worked fine for me. Are you sure this snippet is causing the issue ?

Comment: @Shyju, thank you for responding. The Model property, JS method name and textbox names are diff but ultimately this is what I have it!

Pl. be informed that this entire code is in a partial view.

Comment: If its in a partial, then your `@section ...` would not work (sections are not supported in partials)

Comment: An easier approach would be to just assign you property to a javascript variable inside `<script>` tags - e.g. `var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeTrueCondition)); if (x) { .... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you for your response. As I mentioned, I have the partial views, and I want to embed this JavaScript conditionally. Even within the embedded JS, i want to execute another JS method based on DOM values (text box). Pl. let me know if you need more info. to help me here!

Comment: Its not clear why you would want to generate inline scripts like that. But since this will be evaluated on the server when the page is rendered, then why not refer to the model property that is used in the `value` attribute of the textbox rather than the textbox itself?

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround, you can use `@Html.Raw("<=")` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 3):

### Workaround Options

1. **Avoid JS in Razor views altogether**, and use external JS files. The `@section` in the question seems unnecessary. You can conditionally render scripts without it.

   I think this is the best long-term solution, since:

   - this makes your JS [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)
   - you can't breakpoint JS code in a Razor view from Visual Studio, and using `debugger` leads to messy code.
2. For array and string lengths, there is no need to use `<= 0`. Just use `=== 0` to check for empty.
3. Invert your conditional directions. (Change `<=` to `>=`).

   - Pros: Fewest extra characters inserted, no warnings, least hacky.
   - Cons: Does not preserve Left-Right, which can affect readability.
4. Append `|| 0>0` (`|| false`) to the end of your expression. I chose this Identity Law because then we don't have to worry about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `||` is at the very bottom of the standard Boolean operators, and those are all below the comparison operators. You still have to watch out if you have comments between your conditionals, though.

   - Pros: Concise, preserves Left-Right, doesn't use helper function, pure JS, no warnings.
   - Cons: Looks hacky. May still have errors (see next section on how this bug works)
5. Exclusively use `@**@` Razor comments in views. This prevents comments from showing up in your final code, though.
6. (Don't do this.) Use the `@Html.Raw("<=")` helper function as stated in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651507/4294399). Despite the fact that it generates valid code in the end, it uses a Razor helper for something that *should* be pure JS and messes with Intellisense. Using this completely disables Intellisense for the same line, so if you have a JS syntax error, it will not warn you. (I believe in older versions of the Razor editor, it raised false warnings, but I can no longer verify this.)

### Bug Behavior Information

So I did some research on how this bug works.

It occurs when all of the following conditions are met:

- There is a `<=` (less than or equals) operator in the JS. It must think the `=` is part of a tag name or something.

  - `<`, `<<`, `>`, and `>=` do not cause problems.
- Script is in a `<text></text>` context
- There is a JS comment (line or block) somewhere between the `<=` and the closing `</text>` tag. Razor comments are ok. Exceptions are:

  - There is a `>` operator **or** template string literal (e.g. `` `>` ``) before the offending comment.
  - It cannot be in a normal string literal.

#### Examples

(All these are in `<text>` tags.)

```
1<=0;
// Line comments no good
/* Block comments also no good */
@* No problems with Razor comment *@
```

```
// No problem:
if (0 <= 1){}
0>0;
// Hello
```

```
if (0 <= 1){}
// Some comment here
0>0;
// No good :(
```

Answer (score 3):

I just add this comment `//>` after loop block and worked for me :)

like this:

```
for(let i =0;i<=10;i++){//>//in some where it was working
//your code here
}//>//in some where it was working
```

Comment: I tried this, and I'm still getting a Parser Error. Can you show everything including the `<text>`  tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using the `<text>` block that seems to cause the issue by converting your condition to JS. For example:

```js
var condition = @Model.SomeTrueCondition.ToString().ToLower();
if (condition) {
    function JSMethod() {
        // This statement is no longer a problem if it's not in <text></text>
        if ($('#aTextBox').val().length <= 0 || $('#bTextBox').val().length <= 0) {
            AnotherJSMethod();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```